# Prove that the set {0,1} cannot be an ordered field

Tags: field-theory

I want to use the trichotomy axiom to prove this

Comment: Go ahead and use the trichotomy axiom to prove your title question, and if you have any questions after doing so, or get stuck in the process, then include your workings, and we'll be glad to assist.

Comment: @amWhy I did. I am fine with the fact that 0 cannot be less than one and one cannot be less than zero, but I am still unsure as to why 0 cannot equal 1. I guess I just take this to be a definition?

Comment: It is good practice to include a full problem statement in the body of your Question, even if you think that the title "says it all".  The body of the Question allows you to say more than you've said here.  For example, you could outline or sketch how you attempt to use the trichotomy axiom goes.  If you can explain the difficulty you found, or really anything about the problem that makes it interesting, this will greatly improve the Question.

Answer (score 2):

Use that $-1 = 1$. And in an ordered field $x < y \implies -y < -x$. And $0=1$ is not allowed, so there are only $2$ cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 cases: 1<0, 1>0 or 1=0. Clearly the last case it's not possible. Suppose that 1>0, then, 1+1>1+0, this is, 0>1, so that 1=0 which is a contradiction. In the case that 1<0, we do the same, 1+1<0+1, then 0<1, contradiction too

Comment: I think OP was stuck on the "clearly" part. You can get to the more verbose question if you read the edits of the question.

Comment: 1 cannot be equal to 0. That's clear by definition

Comment: Yeah it was the 0=1 part I was confused on. I ended up using the identity addition axiom for a field and I think I showed it... don't think you can just say it's clear by definition.

Comment: You cannot show it. It's part of the definition. If you use that, you have that is you suppose that 1=0 you cannot get a contradiction by the identity definition

Comment: What about this: 0+0=0 by axiom, since 0=1, this means 1+0 = 1, meaning 1=1, since 1 cannot equal both one and zero we have a contradiction.

Comment: You are basically saying that 1 is not 0 because they are distinct.